# Why Kruskal's algorithm have two Big O?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Learning about Kruskal's algorithm and searching for the BigO of this algorithm, I have ended up finding two answer equally dispersed:

For E = Number of edges in the graph.
For V = Number of vertices in the graph.

Kruskal's algorithm is know to have either:

```
O(E log E)
or
O(E log V)
```

Searching further and going on the [English wiki page of the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Complexity) I've found what seem to be an explanation:

> E is at most V^2 and log(V^2) = 2*log(V) = O(log(V))

But I don't get it, why `2*log(V) = O(log(V))` shouldn't it be `O(2*log(V))`?

Comment: Big `O` notation ignores constant factors, so `2 N = O(N)`. Here are some references: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation).

Comment: Wikipedia also says that both versions are equivalent. It just depends on what you like better.